# Redis shutdown my Magento website

Tags: magento, redis, web, shutdown

I was looking everywhere if I can find an answer to this issue but I was not able.
So my issue is with Redis server, every night at random hour my website simply shut down due to the issue above.
To get my website up I just need to reboot my AWS Instance.

Thank you so much for your help !

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'CredisException' with message ' operation not permitted' in /var/www/lib/Credis/Client.php:704\n

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/lib/Credis/Client.php(538): Credis_Client->read_reply('select')
#1 /var/www/lib/Credis/Client.php(440): Credis_Client->__call('select', Array)
#2 /var/www/app/code/community/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php(135): Credis_Client->select(0)
#3 /var/www/lib/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis->__construct(Array)
#4 /var/www/lib/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true)\n
#5 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(137): Zend_Cache::factory('Varien_Cache_Co...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true)
#6 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->__construct(Array)
#7 /var/www/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core/cache', Array)
#8 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(401): Mage::getModel('core/cache', Array)\n#9 /var/www/app/code/core/Mag in /var/www/lib/Credis/Client.php on line 704
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like your redis instance is left open on the internet and you've been hacked.

Make sure you secure correctly your instance.

[Gist explaining the problem](https://gist.github.com/antirez/12d60c950fbfd8c8837e)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information !
Do you have any tutorial on how to secure ? It's not me who set up the redis server so it's hard to find how to do it...
Because to access to my redis server I have to enter password.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Unfortunately I do not. What I can recommend to you as a first step (since you mentioned AWS) is to follow the [basic guidance](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1233/) provided by amazon when creating instances.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I achieve to stop error by secure the Redis port.

Comment: Hi @magentodev if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.